# Degree of the zero polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In “Linear Algebra Done Right” by Axler, while defining the degree of a polynomial, it is stated that the zero polynomial is said to have degree $- \infty$. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is largely a matter of convention, and it rarely comes up in applications. One reason is for this convention is this: Nonzero polynomials satisfy the identity
$$\deg(pq) = \deg p + \deg q,$$
and we can extend this to the zero polynomial if we declare $\deg 0 = -\infty$ and use the convention that $a + (-\infty) = -\infty$ for $a$ any nonnegative integer (or again $-\infty$).

Comment: Oh, I see. But if it's just a matter of convention, can one equally define it to be $+ \infty$ as well?

Comment: I suppose that's still consistent with the identity, which is interesting. But with that convention we'd have to say that the zero polynomial has the highest degree of all polynomials, which sounds peculiar and would probably require restatement of some theorems that involve polynomial degree. In practice this isn't an issue, I'm not sure that I've heard any reference to $\deg 0$ since I took linear algebra myself before now.

Comment: @jobin You also have $\deg(p+q) =\max(\deg p, \deg q)$, and this still works for $p=0$ or $q=0$ if you take $\deg(0) = -\infty$, but not if you take $\deg(0) =  +\infty$. Degrees form a [max-plus algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra) and you need  $-\infty$ because it's the identity element for the $\max$ operation.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, @MJD. (Of course, you mean $\deg(p + q) \leq \max(\deg p, \deg q)$.)

Comment: @Travis: wiki says; the degree of 0 polynomial is either left undefined, or is defined to be negative (usually $−1$ or $−\infty$). You just gave an explanation for $-\infty$ what about $-1$?

Comment: If by "just" you mean almost 18 months ago, then yes, I did! Anyway, it's not clear why someone would use $-1$ here; if one follows the citation on Wikipedia, one gets to this text https://books.google.at/books?id=rUApHgaTVx0C&lpg=PA279&vq=%22zero+polynomial%22&pg=PA233&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22zero%20polynomial%22&f=false There's no explanation given, and notice that with this convention the statement of the text's Exercise E3 is false. In fact, the author appears to have changed the convention to $\deg 0 := -\infty$ in the third edition of the cited text.

Answer (score 1):

To make it consistent with the definitions. We like to have

$$\deg(fg) = \deg(f)+\deg(g)$$

It is just a convenient way of defining the degree of the zero polynomial. For example, since $0\cdot x^2 = 0$, we have

$$\deg(0\cdot x^2) = \deg(0) + \deg(x^2) = -\infty+2 =-\infty$$